# Why does appreciation make us happy?

Tags: emotion, personality

Why does one crave facebook likes or a pat on the back. Our actions are always governed by this phenomenon, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I originally read your question as "the experience of appreciating things", but it sounds more like you are talking about accumulating "social capital" - likes, followers, reputation, etc.

Comment: Ya the latter. I wish to understand the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: [As humans who experience anticipation...thus increasing our chances of survival.](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-we-addicted-to-inform/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement#Reinforcement

Comment: Some need that reassurance that they are still valid, that they looks good / sexy, that their posessions are the luxurious / fines / shiniest from the city and so on..

Comment: @adrianlazar.tm - Welcome to CogSci and thanks for your contribution. However, answers should not be just a one-liner, instead they should elaborate on the key issyes and be backed up by references. I have converted your answer to a comment.

Answer (score 3):

From a biological viewpoint, these experiences are associated with the release of neurotransmitters like dopamine and oxytocin, which activate the "reward pathway" of the brain that is associated with feelings of happiness and mood alleviation. Since these are pleasurable experiences, we crave more and more of it, which is why a lot of our actions are governed by it.

**References**:

The Science of Happiness. (2016). More Good Deeds. Retrieved 19 April 2017, from https://www.moregooddeeds.org/blog/2017/1/20/the-science-of-happiness

Fehlhaber, K. (2012). The Reward Pathway Reinforces Behavior - Knowing Neurons. Knowing Neurons. Retrieved 19 April 2017, from http://knowingneurons.com/2012/10/31/the-reward-pathway-reinforces-behavior/

Icahn School of Medicine | Neuroscience Department | Nestler Lab | Brain Reward Pathways. (2017). Neuroscience.mssm.edu. Retrieved 19 April 2017, from http://neuroscience.mssm.edu/nestler/brainRewardpathways.html

Know your brain: Reward system. (2015). Neuroscientifically Challenged. Retrieved 19 April 2017, from http://www.neuroscientificallychallenged.com/blog/know-your-brain-reward-system

Comment: Hi Aman, Welcome at CogSci. Do you have any references that could back up these statements?

Comment: [link](https://www.moregooddeeds.org/blog/2017/1/20/the-science-of-happiness)
This link has the explanations for the release of oxytocin and dopamine, along with other hormones and neurotransmitters

Comment: More information about the rewards pathway can be found in these sites:
[link](http://knowingneurons.com/2012/10/31/the-reward-pathway-reinforces-behavior/)
[link](http://neuroscience.mssm.edu/nestler/brainRewardpathways.html)
[link](http://www.neuroscientificallychallenged.com/blog/know-your-brain-reward-system)

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal - please include those references in your answer proper

Comment: I have an objection to this answer: In my opinion, it answers the question **how** appreciation makes us happy from a biological point of view. Moreover, I claim that the reason for feeling happiness, that is **why**, lies outside of the domain of biological explanations. Regards, and hopefully a constructive debate.

Comment: Maybe I could've phrased my response differently, but just to clarify the "why" is the activation of the reward pathway of the brain, the rest, I agree, is the "how". Also, the same situation can be analysed in terms of the cognitive and sociocultural levels of analyses as well. Since I only know the biological explanation for this phenomenon, I've confined my answer to that.